# Is there a way to make separate a column depending on the values of another column in python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, data-analysis

I am writing a code in python to analyze my data for my thesis. From the experiment I am getting a large set of data. In the first part of the script, it is generating an output something like the following:

```
GateVolt      Field      HallVolt 
0             1500          76       
0             1490          75
0             1485          74
.               .            .
.               .            .
0.1           1485          72
0.1           1476          70
.               .            .
.               .            .
0.2           1470          67
0.2           1465          62
.               .            .
.               .            .
.               .            .
```

Based on this output the further analysis is done.
The code I wrote:

```
    #Read the CSV that contains all the data

    field = np.array([])
    hallVolt = np.array([])
    gate_voltage = np.array([])
    channel_voltage = np.array([])
    voltage_Counter = 0

    for lineIndex in range(len(fileLines)):
        currentLine = fileLines[lineIndex]
        dataSegment = currentLine.split()
        field = np.append(Field, float(dataSegment[9])) #This is milli Tesla
        hallVolt = np.append(hallVolt, float(dataSegment[5])) #This is milli Volt
        channel_voltage = np.append(channel_voltage, float(dataSegment[2])) #This is Volt
        VG = float(dataSegment[6]) - float(dataSegment[2])/2
        gate_voltage = np.append(gate_voltage, np.round(VG, 2)) #This is Volt
        if lineIndex > 1 and VG != gate_voltage[lineIndex-1]:
            voltage_Counter = voltage_Counter + 1

    HallVoltage = hallVolt-((max(hallVolt))+min(hallVolt))/2
    HallVoltage_Norm = HV/((max(HV)-min(HV))/2)
```

So what I want my code to do to make separate columns for 'Hall voltage' and 'Magnetic Field' for each 'gate voltage', something like the following:

```
GateVolt Field  HallVoltage  GateVolt  Field  HallVolt   GateVolt  Field  HallVolt
0        1500          76     0.1       1485     72       0.2      1470        67
0        1490          75     0.1       1476     70       0.2      1465        62
0        1485          74      .         .        .        .         .        .
.          .            .      .         .        .        .         .        .
.          .            .      .         .        .        .         .        .
.          .            .      .         .        .        .         .        .
```

In the end, I want to plot 'Hall Voltage' vs 'Field' and also do some analysis and fitting and some more plotting for different gate voltages.

I am almost a newbie to coding and python and I have no idea what to do next to get such an output. Is there any way to achieve what I want to do? 
Thanking in advance!!! :)

Comment: List append is much faster (and easier to use) than `np.append`.  You can create an array from the list after the loop.   For a display with column headings `pandas` is better than `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate these tables by using `groupby` as follow:

```
x = df.groupby(['GateVolt'])
for state, frame in x:
    print(f"{state!r}")
    print("------------------------")
    print(frame, end="\n\n")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But it would be better if I can separate them in columns, because, in the end I would have to plot them with matplotlib.